# Should I create a new question or expand my first one?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions

"Does anyone know whether the 'plastic bags' that food waste should be in are separate from the plastic bags that already are used for general trash?" This question came to mind after I [recently asked](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/77156/are-there-de-minimis-exceptions-to-food-waste-for-trash-collection?noredirect=1#comment163276_77156) whether this would be an example of the purpose of *de minimus* exceptions.

In the comments, one user wasn't sure how my scenario would play out to begin with. After all, how would you go about "not using 13 gallon plastic kitchen bags or 30 gallon plastic trash can liners to consolidate your trash inside your house or apartment [...]"? Considering that the sources I cited seem to require plastic bags specifically in the context of "food waste," I'm not sure whether these city instructions are referring to *those* plastic bags.

Would expanding the question be better than asking a new question? Or, would it be acceptable to create a new question since the focus would now be on identifying whether the "plastic bags" must be specifically for food waste? I don't want to lose any rep. and thus am asking here first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## If you're clarifying the original question.

You should edit that question so that it reads sensibly, as if everything before it was just a draft.

- Such edits should not invalidate existing answers. Only add information that answers can be revised to address without fundamental change to their meaning. Don't remove information that is crucial to answers (though of course remove information that was never relevant to the key question and is not necessary to address for that key question to be answered).
- Such edits should not be separate paragraphs or sections, especially not with a heading like "Edit:" or "Update 2"; this is Stack Exchange, not Reddit, anybody can review the edit history if they need to. Integrate the details where they are sensible and appropriate.

## If you're following up on an answer.

You should post a new question, because that's literally what it is. Link back to the first question so that readers have context and users who post an answer can avoid repeating themselves in unnecessary detail.

Comment: Thanks! Just created it here: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/77373/are-city-regulations-stating-food-waste-should-be-in-platic-bags-require-bags.